# PowerShell: Advice on structuring a recursive function to return all URLs on a website

Tags: powershell, recursion, web-scraping

I've attempted to put together a website scraper using PowerShell that will return all the links on a page, but I'm getting some unexpected bugs with it, that seem to be linked to how I'm handling recursion.

A brief description of how the code is meant to work is as follows:

1. Get all links on a specific page.
2. Compare all links found with all previously searched links, return only those links that haven't been searched yet, and filter out any links outside a specified domain.
3. If there is one or more valid links that hasn't been searched yet, return first search link from list. If there are no more valid search links, return 'NoMoreLinks'.
4. If 'NoMoreLinks' then return final result, otherwise recurse to step 1, using new search URL.

The main problem seems to be something related to how the stored results are being used. There's quite a bit of code I'm about to share, so I'm not expecting one person to fix it all, but any advice related to design/implementation improvements would be welcome.

The current code:

```
Clear-Host

$finalres = @()

Function Get-WebsiteObject {

    param (

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $searchedUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $outerText,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $href

    )

    $WebsiteObject = New-Object System.Object
    $WebsiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name searchedUrl -Value $searchedUrl
    $WebsiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name outerText -Value $outerText
    $WebsiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name href -Value $href
    $WebsiteObject

}


Function Get-WebsiteLinks {

    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $inputUrlString
    )

    begin {
        $returnUrlArray = @()
    }

    process {

        (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $inputUrlString).Links | % {

            $outerText = $_.outerText
            $href = if ( $_.href.Substring(0,1) -eq '/' ) { ($inputUrlString + $_.href).ToLower() } else { $_.href.ToLower() }

            #$innerText = $_.innerText
            #$outerHTML = (($_.outerHTML) -replace "`t", '') -replace "`n", ''
            #$tagName = $_.tagName

            $returnUrlArray += (Get-WebsiteObject -searchedUrl $inputUrlString -outerText $outerText -href $href)

        }


    }

    end {

        $returnUrlArray

    }

}


Function Get-SearchLinks {

    # Input: All found links, all previously searched links
    # Output: A link that hasn't been searched yet, or an empty string if no further URLs to search

    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string[]] $allLinks,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string[]] $allSearchedLinks,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $linkFilter

    )

    begin {

        $returnUrlString = 'NoMoreURLs'

    }

    process {



        #N.B. PassThru used to get values from Compare-Object rather than a comparison table

        $firstUnsearchedUrl = ((Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $allLinks -DifferenceObject $allLinks -PassThru) | ? { $_ -like "*" + linkFilter + "*" } | Select -First 1 )

        if ($firstUnsearchedUrl.Length -ne 0) { 

            $returnUrlString = $firstUnsearchedUrl.ToLower()

        }

    }

    end {

        $returnUrlString   

    }

}


Function Get-AllWebsiteLinks {

    params (

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $startUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $domainFilter #Only search for links in this domain, to stop searching the whole web!

    )

    #Initial
    if ($finalres.Length -eq 0) {
        $finalres += (Get-WebsiteObject -searchedUrl $startUrl.ToLower() -outerText '[Homepage]' -href $startUrl.ToLower())
        $finalres = Get-WebsiteLinks -inputUrlString $startUrl.ToLower()
    }

    $allLinks = $finalres.href.ToLower() | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
    $allSearchLinks = $finalres.searchedUrl | Sort-Object | Get-Unique

    $searchUrl = Get-SearchLinks -allLinks $allLinks -allSearchedLinks $allSearchLinks -linkFilter $domainFilter
    Write-Output $searchUrl

    if ($searchUrl -eq 'NoMoreURLs') {
        $finalres | Out-GridView
    }
    else {
        $finalres += Get-WebsiteLinks -inputUrlString $searchUrl
        Get-AllWebsiteLinks -startUrl $searchUrl -domainFilter $domainFilter
    }

}

Get-AllWebsiteLinks -startUrl 'http://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone' -domainFilter 'webscraper.io'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
Is this supposed to work as a framework for every website ? Because you say "a specific page". If you'd like to scrape a specific page, you care to share and show us what it is you'd like?

Comment: For the time being, it's best to assume I'd like the code to work on multiple websites. The URL listed in the code should give a usable example. The scraper should also be able to handle relative links as well as absolute links.

Comment: You mention that you're "getting some unexpected bugs with it" - can you describe the actual behavior you're seeing (versus what you expect)?